# how to access custom option of item before placing it into cart

Tags: custom-options

I have created observer for sales_quote_add_item  event, i am using `udropship_vendor` module for vendor management. So price of a product  is attached to product in custom options.  I couldn't able to fetch  `udmp_vendor_data`  custom option please suggest.

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
echo '<pre>';  print_r( $item);  exit;
```

**Is giving (part of an output)**

```
[udmp_vendor_data] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Option Object
(
[_item:protected] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item Object
     *RECURSION*[_product:protected] => Azri_Unsetdeleverydate_Model_Catalog_Product Object
     *RECURSION*[_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract [_eventObject:protected] => object[_resourceName:protected] =>sales/quote_item_option                
     [_resource:protected] => [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => sales/quote_item_option_collection          
     [_cacheTag:protected] => [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
                              [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
                              [_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [option_id] => 195991
                                    [item_id] => 25349
                                    [product_id] => 5566
                                    [code] => udmp_vendor_data
                                    [value] => a:25:{s:17:"vendor_product_id";s:6:"245116";s:9:"vendor_id";s:4:"3748";s:10:"product_id";s:4:"5566";s:8:"priority";s:4:"9999";s:12:"carrier_code";N;s:10:"vendor_sku";s:11:"87859_200-2";s:11:"vendor_cost";N;s:9:"stock_qty";N;s:10:"backorders";s:1:"0";s:14:"shipping_price";N;s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:12:"reserved_qty";N;s:11:"avail_state";N;s:10:"avail_date";N;s:12:"vendor_title";N;s:12:"vendor_price";s:7:"27.0000";s:5:"state";s:3:"new";s:13:"special_price";N;s:17:"special_from_date";N;s:15:"special_to_date";N;s:11:"state_descr";N;s:12:"freeshipping";s:1:"0";s:16:"udropship_vendor";s:4:"3748";s:5:"label";s:9:"Lieferant";s:5:"value";s:15:"Propagroup GmbH";}
                                )
                               [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
                               [_origData:protected] => Array
                                  (
                                     [option_id] => 195991
                                     [item_id] => 25349
                                     [product_id] => 5566
                                     [code] => udmp_vendor_data
                                     [value] => a:25:{s:17:"vendor_product_id";s:6:"245116";s:9:"vendor_id";s:4:"3748";s:10:"product_id";s:4:"5566";s:8:"priority";s:4:"9999";s:12:"carrier_code";N;s:10:"vendor_sku";s:11:"87859_200-2";s:11:"vendor_cost";N;s:9:"stock_qty";N;s:10:"backorders";s:1:"0";s:14:"shipping_price";N;s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:12:"reserved_qty";N;s:11:"avail_state";N;s:10:"avail_date";N;s:12:"vendor_title";N;s:12:"vendor_price";s:7:"27.0000";s:5:"state";s:3:"new";s:13:"special_price";N;s:17:"special_from_date";N;s:15:"special_to_date";N;s:11:"state_descr";N;s:12:"freeshipping";s:1:"0";s:16:"udropship_vendor";s:4:"3748";s:5:"label";s:9:"Lieferant";s:5:"value";s:15:"Propagroup GmbH";}
                                   )
                                [_idFieldName:protected] => option_id
                                [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                                [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array()
                                [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array()
                                )
                                )
```

I have tried    `$item->getOption() and  $item->getOptionbycode('udmp_vendor_data')` in   by using both or not working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $options = array();
    $optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids');
    if ($optionIds) {
        $options = array();
        foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
            $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
            if ($option) {
                $itemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());
                $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                    ->setOption($option)
                    ->setConfigurationItem($item)
                    ->setConfigurationItemOption($itemOption);

                if ('file' == $option->getType()) {
                    $downloadParams = $item->getFileDownloadParams();
                    if ($downloadParams) {
                        $url = $downloadParams->getUrl();
                        if ($url) {
                            $group->setCustomOptionDownloadUrl($url);
                        }
                        $urlParams = $downloadParams->getUrlParams();
                        if ($urlParams) {
                            $group->setCustomOptionUrlParams($urlParams);
                        }
                    }
                }

                $options[] = array(
                    'label' => $option->getTitle(),
                    'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue($itemOption->getValue()),
                    'print_value' => $group->getPrintableOptionValue($itemOption->getValue()),
                    'option_id' => $option->getId(),
                    'option_type' => $option->getType(),
                    'custom_view' => $group->isCustomizedView()
                );
            }
        }

        print_r($options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$product = $item->getProduct();
      $data =  Mage::helper('udropship/item')->getItemOption( $product, 'udmp_vendor_data');
      $vendor_data = unserialize($data);

This has worked for me.